# Hello. I would like to know the 1972 British patent number for the Terfenadine drug composition assigned to Merrel Dow. Thank you

Tags: citation, terfenadine, gb

This British patent was cited in: Merrell Dow Pharmaceuticals Inc. and others vs. HN Norton & Co. Limited, United Kingdom House of Lord Decisions [1995] UKHL 14 on 26th of October 1995. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was annoying to search for as the company cited as Merrell Dow didn't have any relevant patents dating back to 1972. No doubt this is because company names often change over time especially after mergers. The closest thing I could find for a UK patent application is [GB1412605A](https://patents.google.com/patent/GB1412605A/en?q=(antihistamine)&assignee=Richardson%20Merrell%20Inc&before=priority:19740101&after=priority:19650101). The assignee for that application was Richardson Merrell Inc. and the inventor was Albert A Carr. I think you'll likely find the patent of interest among the [results of this search](https://patents.google.com/?q=antihistamine&inventor=Albert%20A%20Carr&assignee=Richardson-Merrell%20Inc,Richardson%20Merrell%20Inc&sort=old).

Comment: Hello Mr Eric: Thank you for the reply.  I am much appreciative of the efforts put into the Hunt for this particular patent by your good self. Thank you.

Comment: @farmacist If the answer suits you, please consider upvoting it or even accepting it by clicking on the check mark. That’s how the site is designed to work.